# Password protected zipping command is not working

Tags: shell-script, solaris, zip

I have a assignment to create a password protected zip file from script and sent it over email.

I am using below command over **sparc-sun-solaris2.10** environment to create a password protected zip file.

```
`zip -j -P password file1.csv.zip file1.csv`
```

It is failing with the below error message:

```
`zip warning: name not matched: file1.csv`
`zip error: Nothing to do! (file1.csv.zip)`
```

It has got successful once but for subsequent runs it is failing continuously.

Any help upon this much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This warning from `zip`:

```
`zip warning: name not matched: file1.csv
```

is given when the file specified doesn't exist.  Since that means your `zip` command doesn't have any input files, it doesn't have anything to put into the output zip file, so you get

```
`zip error: Nothing to do! (file1.csv.zip)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GPG toll like that:

```
gpg -c file.tar
```

Then set the password.

To unprotect use:

```
gpg file.tar.gpg
```

Comment: How does this create a password-protected zip file, though?